# Additional columns to Select(Max) query

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have my SQL code working to return Max t.[CreatedDateTime] (See Below) giving me the correct results, however I wish to add an additional column t.[Owner] and not display the [CreatedDateTime] in the results however still basing the results on Max([t.CreatedDateTime])

```
SELECT i.[RecID] as AssigneeID, max(t.[CreatedDateTime]) CreatedDateTime
FROM Incident as i
Join Task as t On i.[RecID] =  t.[ParentLink_RecID] 
WHERE i.[Status] <> 'Closed'
AND t.[OwnerTeam] IS NOT NULL
group by i.[RecID]
Order By i.[RecID] DESC
```

**Current Results**

```
AssigneeID              CreatedDateTime 
FFFE53B2305D47388937D1F5B6722DF3    2013-05-13 14:36:55.000
FFD64AD977A449258A88B9A404795631    2013-05-21 14:11:28.000
FFD557F622A34FD1A386B427B66ADAFC    2013-04-26 12:32:05.000
```

**Required Results**

```
AssigneeID                          Owner
FFFE53B2305D47388937D1F5B6722DF3    Bob
FFD64AD977A449258A88B9A404795631    Fred
FFD557F622A34FD1A386B427B66ADAFC    Harry
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance..

Comment: It sounds like you are seeking a solution to the common `greatest-n-per-group` problem.  I've added that tag, since this has been answered a zillion times.  You want to combine that with the `sql-server-2005` tag to find solutions specific to your brand of RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say, but based on the [columnName] syntax, it looks like you are using MS SQLServer. If so, then you can use RANK() OR ROW_NUMBER() for an efficient solution.

```
with rankedResult as (
  select i.[AssigneeID],
         t.[Owner],
         row_number() over( partition by i.[AssigneeID] 
                            order by t.[CreatedDateTime] desc, t.[Owner] ) seq
    from Incident i
    join Task t
      on t.[ParentLink_RecID] = i.[RecID]
   where i.[Status] <> 'Closed'
     and t.[OwnerTeam] is not null
)
select [AssigneeID],
       [Owner]
  from rankedResult
 where seq=1
;
```

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'RecID'.

Comment: Yes it is MS SQL Server, i tried your sugestion, however got the error above?

Comment: @SQL_Newbie - I don't know what the problem is since I'm using the same join condition as in your question. I modified the query to use [columnName] syntax, but that has never made a difference on my SqlServer installation. I do know that using RANK() as I have shown works for your type of problem - I do it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could just join your current query results with a Task table (getting a Owner column data) on a record ID column.
For ex:

```
select t1.AssigneeID, t2.Owner from (your current query) t1, Task t2 where t1.AssigneeID = t2.ParentLink_RecID
order by 1 desc
```

Full ex:

```
select t1.[AssigneeID] as AssigneeID, t2.[Owner] as Owner 
from Task t2 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT I. [RecID] as AssigneeID, max(t.[CreatedDateTime]) CreatedDateTime FROM Incident as i Join Task as t On i.[RecID] = t.[ParentLink_RecID] WHERE i.[Status] <> 'Closed' AND t.[OwnerTeam] IS NOT NULL group by i.[RecID]) t1 
on t2.[ParentLink_RecID] = t1.[AssigneeID] 
order by t1.[AssigneeID] desc
```

Comment: sorry, im unclear what you mean, could you give me a fuller example/

Comment: try my full example - I don't have your scheme and don't know what DB you use but basing it on your example query syntax this should work.

Comment: in my query I basically just joining your query results (from your example) with another Task table (t2) to retrieve an Owner column data for collection of RecId values that you've got as the results in your first query (t1). 
You can't just add additional Owner column to your base query because each column that isn't used in a Group (aggregation) function - you have to mention in a group by clause - so in that case you'll have wrong grouping results.

Comment: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: You just should remove an order by clause from your inner select.
I've edited my example - now it should work.

Comment: your update example worked however I'm getting duplicates in my results, please see below. I just need the AssigneeID with the Select Max CreatedDateTime.

Comment: Sorry, that might have happened because I don't know the structure of your tables - I assume that RecID is a primary key for Incident table so it seems that ParentLink_RecID is a foreign key to this column in Task table and it's not unique - so that's why it can give you duplicates on joining.
Try to use left join statement - i'll fix my example.

Comment: Last addition - if left join won't work properly try change order of joining in my example to:

select t1.[AssigneeID] as AssigneeID, t2.[Owner] as Owner from 
Task t2 LEFT JOIN
(SELECT i.[RecID] as AssigneeID, max(t.[CreatedDateTime]) CreatedDateTime
FROM Incident as i
Join Task as t On i.[RecID] =  t.[ParentLink_RecID] 
WHERE i.[Status] <> 'Closed'
AND t.[OwnerTeam] IS NOT NULL
group by i.[RecID]) t1 on t2.[ParentLink_RecID] = t1.[AssigneeID] 
order by t1.[AssigneeID] desc

Comment: AssigneeID   Owner
FFFE53B2305D47388937D1F5B6722DF3 Bob
FFFE53B2305D47388937D1F5B6722DF3 Mary
FFD64AD977A449258A88B9A404795631 Harry
FFD64AD977A449258A88B9A404795631 Fred

Comment: Tried your suggestion, I still get duplicate values in AssigneeID?

Comment: Did you tried second option (I edited it in my answer now)? If so, please describe relationship between Task and Incidents tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT AssignedID, Owner
FROM
( 
 SELECT i.[RecID] as AssigneeID, max(t.[CreatedDateTime]) CreatedDateTime, t.[Owner]
FROM Incident as i
Join Task as t On i.[RecID] =  t.[ParentLink_RecID] 
WHERE i.[Status] <> 'Closed'
AND t.[OwnerTeam] IS NOT NULL
group by i.[RecID]
) S
Order By AssignedID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT x.AssigneeID, tt.Owner
FROM (
   SELECT i.[RecID] as AssigneeID, max(t.[CreatedDateTime]) CreatedDateTime
   FROM Incident as i
   Join Task as t On i.[RecID] =  t.[ParentLink_RecID] 
   WHERE i.[Status] <> 'Closed'
   AND t.[OwnerTeam] IS NOT NULL
   group by i.[RecID]
) x
JOIN Task as TT ON (x.RecID = tt.ParentLine_RecID)
ORDER BY x.AssigneeID DESC
```